# Invoking PMD from java interface

Tags: java, pmd

I need my interface to invoke PMD plugin, I want it to be running for analyze the selected file. I've already tried the code that running PMD from java project, but I do not know how to pass the selected file to PMD.run class which suppose to run the PMD.

```
String src_folder = ("E:/CS lecture/4.2/pmd-master/pmd-java/src/main/java");
    String output_format="text";
    String rulesets= "java/rule";
    String[] arguments = {   "-d", src_folder, "-f", output_format,  "-R", rulesets};
  PMDCommandLineInterface.run(arguments);
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve that the [Maven plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/) can't? Or, perhaps, the [Gradle plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/pmd_plugin.html)?

Comment: I'm trying to make some modifications for the PMD plugin which it's an open source tool. I already added rules for logical errors. And I need to invoke it in my project's interface.

Answer (score 0):

It works when I assign the file's directory path into the variable src_folder.

```
String src_folder = ("E:/.../fileviewer.java");  
    String output_format="xml";
    String rulesets= "java-unusedcode";
    String[] arguments = {   "-d", src_folder, "-f", output_format,  "-R", rulesets };
    PMDCommandLineInterface.run(arguments);
```

Further see: http://pmd.sourceforge.net/pmd-4.3.0/running.html